# String check with list of strings

Tags: python

What would be the quickest way to make sure the following is trusted:

```
email = "foobar@gmail.com"

trusted = [".co.uk", ".com", ".net", ".edu", ".ac.uk"]
```

Comment: trusted, explain properly

Comment: Do you mean `if any(email.endswith(s) for s in trusted)` ?

Comment: endswith() method in string

Answer (score 1):

you can use filter for these sorts of things:

```
list(filter(lambda x: email.endswith(x),trusted))
```